# ERROR On Create Invoiceexception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Cannot create an empty shipment.' in app/Mage.php:595

Tags: php, magento

I getting the above error when i using this code to create transaction and shipment. Not working only for bundle product. Other simple/configurable products are working fine with same code.

```
$shipment = $order->prepareShipment($qtysForProducts);
   $shipment->addTrack($track);
   $shipment->addComment($comment);
   $shipment->sendNewEmail(TRUE, $shipmentComment,$newSkuCustomer);
   $shipment->register();
   $shippmentId = $shipment->save()->getId();                       

$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
   ->addObject($shipment)
   ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
   ->save();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Cannot create an empty shipment.' message fired when shipment is not registered or don't have items. Check $qtysForProducts array and try next code:

```
$shipment = $order->prepareShipment($qtysForProducts);
$shipment->addComment($comment);
if ($shipment) {
    $shipment->register();
    $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
    try {
        $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
            ->addObject($shipment)
            ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
            ->save();
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        Mage::log($e->getMessage(), Zend_Log::ERR);
    }
}
```